# Java 7 G1GC strange behaviour

Tags: multithreading, garbage-collection, java-7, heap-memory, g1gc

Recently I have tried to use G1GC from jdk1.7.0-17 in my java processor which is processing a lot of similar messages received from an MQ (about 15-20 req/sec). Every message is processed in the separate thread (about 100 threads in stable state) that serviced by Java limited thread pool. Surprisingly, I detected the strange behaviour - as soon as GC starts the full gc cycle it begins to use significant processing time (up to 100% CPU and even more). I was doing refactoring of the code several times having a goal to optimizing it and doing it more lightweight. But without any significant result - the behaviour is the same. I use the 4-core 64-bit machine with Debian OS (2.6.32-5 kernel). May someone help me to understand and resolve the situation?
Below are depicted some illustrations for listed above issue.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: When you say using 100% cpu: is that 100% for 1 core or 100% on all 4 cores? Also when using 100% try to hook Jconsole and check which threads are runnable, is it really GC using the cpu or anything else?

Comment: When I'm talking about CPU usage I mean the CPU usage (including GC) for all 4 cores together. Unfortunately, the application is located on remote server (without GUI)  and I cannot run some tool with graphical interface there. Note that I have used custom monitor which getting info from Java MBeans (like JConsole). The illustration is grabbed from there.

Comment: I have looked into JMap output also - there aren't any blocked or suspicious threads. But when I'm looking into HTop output I see that only a few my application threads are in run state (not in sleep state) and eats each about 2-3% of CPU. But there is one thread (I guess it is GC) that eats near to 100% (92-94%).

Comment: One (gc) thread can not eat 4 x 100% cpu, so something else is going on. You can do stackdumps on your remote machine and see which thread is doing what.

Comment: Not so. The GC thread that I talking about occupy 1 core wholly. and please note that GC is doing so while switching to full GC cycle  only.

Comment: Can you post your JVM parameters?

Answer (score 0):

> Surprisingly, I detected the strange behaviour - as soon as GC starts
>   the full gc cycle...

Unfortunately, this is not a surprise because for the G1 GC implemented within the JVM uses just one hardware thread (vCPU) to execute the Full GC so the idea is to minimize the number of Full GCs. Please, you should keep in mind this collector is recommended for configurations with several cores (of course it does not impact on the Full GC, but impacts on allocation and parallel collections) and big heaps I think bigger than 8GB.

According to Oracle:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/g1_gc.html

> The Garbage-First (G1) garbage collector is a server-style garbage
>   collector, targeted for **multiprocessor machines with large memorie**s.
>   It attempts to meet garbage collection (GC) pause time goals with high
>   probability while achieving high throughput. Whole-heap operations,
>   such as global marking, are performed concurrently with the
>   application threads. This prevents interruptions proportional to heap
>   or live-data size.

In this article there is an explanation about the Full GC single thread in this collector.

https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/part-1-introduction-g1-garbage-collector

> Finally and unfortunately, G1 also has to deal with the dreaded Full
>   GC. While G1 is ultimately trying to avoid Full GC’s, they are still a
>   harsh reality especially in improperly tuned environments. **Given that
>   G1 is targeting larger heap sizes, the impact of a Full GC can be
>   catastrophic to in-flight processing and SLAs. One of the primary
>   reasons is that Full GCs are still a single-threaded operation in G1**.
>   Looking at causes, the first, and most avoidable, is related to
>   Metaspace.

By the way, it seems to be the newest version of Java (10) is going to include a G1 with the capability of executing Full GCs in parallel.

https://www.opsian.com/blog/java-10-with-g1/

> Java 10 reduces Full GC pause times by iteratively improving on its
>   existing algorithm. Until Java 10 G1 Full GCs ran in a single thread.
>   That’s right - your 32 core server and it’s 128GB will stop and pause
>   until a single thread takes out the garbage.

Perhaps, you should tune the metaspace or increase the heap or you can use other collector such as the parallel GC.